# Booting from Ubuntu USB on Dell Inspiron 5000

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, dell

I am trying to install Ubuntu from a USB on a Dell Inspiron 5000.  I made the bootable USB with the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator.  I manged to boot into it using my regular machine, so I think the bootable USB is working.

But the Dell laptop I am trying to actually install it on though keeps booting into Windows.  I have tried changing the boot order in the BIOS which I accessed via <kbd>F2</kbd>.  I tried using <kbd>F12</kbd> for a one-time boot and that did the same thing.

I tried booting from Windows itself using "Advanced Startup" in Windows.  I selected "Restart now" and went to "Use Device" and Windows listed "ubuntu" as an option.  Again however, when I selected this, it ultimately booted into Windows.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you turn off fast start up / hibernate in Windows? Also, after ensuring your USB is first boot priority, try shutting down completely then turning on, not restarting from Windows.

Comment: Did you remember to disable secure boot?